# How to set the specified ssh log file in ssh client pc?

Tags: ssh, logs, openssh

To set the specified sshd log file in ssh server pc this way.

```
vim /etc/rsyslog.conf
local0.*     /var/log/sshd.log 
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
SyslogFacility local0
```

To create the log file:

```
touch /var/log/sshd.log
```

To restart all services.

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
systemctl restart sshd
```

To get all the ssh log in ssh client pc this way.

```
sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S:whoami: "
export HISTTIMEFORMAT
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'      
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Now to get all  ssh log record.

```
history |grep  ssh
```

My question is that how to set  the specified ssh log file in ssh client pc,instead of sshd log file in ssh server pc?

Here is my try in ssh client pc.

```
vim /etc/rsyslog.conf
local0.*     /var/log/ssh.log 
vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config
SyslogFacility local0
```

To create the log file:

```
touch /var/log/ssh.log
```

To restart all services.

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
reboot
```

An error occur when to login my vps from ssh client pc:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 56: Bad configuration option: syslogfacility
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Is there a way to set the specified ssh log file in ssh client pc instead of logging it in history?
History command can log all the ssh action taken in my ssh client pc,i want all the log info in a single specified file such as /var/log/ssh.log.
Please don't tell me this way.

```
history |grep  ssh  >> /var/log/ssh.log
```

Comment: You want to log ... the shell commands? ... of the remote session on the local side?

Comment: To log all ssh action taken in the ssh client  pc on a ssh.log file in the ssh client pc.

Comment: is the client OpenSSH? I know that PuTTY, for example, lets you set up a local log file.

Comment: The client os is debian ,client soft is openssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following on the client:

```
script logfile.log
ssh into the machine
do whatever you need
exit from ssh
exit from script
```

It will log everything that happens inside the script session to the file specified at the beginning until you exit.

Beware of commands that manipulate the whole screen (vi, top, etc...) as they will generate garbage to the log.

Comment: My  companion can't do it,so it is not a good idea.

Comment: I know this is not a perfect solution, but given your previous info it does the job. Can you tell what's wrong so I'm able to try to fix? Maybe I can even think of something different...